# How to get a stack-trace via api-call in xdebug?

Tags: php, api, stack-trace, trace, xdebug

We are using **xdebug** and the tracing works as advertised **during code execution** via..

```
 function someGetUsersHelper() {
     xdebug_start_trace();
     [SOME CODE HERE]
     xdebug_stop_trace();
}
```

It however only traces the wrapped part of the code if the page/script is executed via loading the full page in the browser via requesting

```
index.php
```

**But tracing does not work, when we call the function as an api call via**

```
index.php?api=getUsers
```

Even though the very same function is executed successfully it does not trace.

As an additional note: Tracing also works if the function is called from phpunit testcases or if we set xdebug.auto_trace = 1 in the php.ini, but that leaves us with a very long, messed up trace file.

**So the question is this:**

- What might be the issue/reason for this and how can we manage to get the
  desired clear and succinct trace via api call?

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could not say why the trace is not working. But you could try this:

1. Add the option `xdebug.trace_enable_trigger=1` in your php configuration
2. Now you could start a xdebug by adding `XDEBUG_TRACE` as POST/GET Parameter or as a cookie

There is also a Firefox Plugin called *Easy XDebug* to set the flags

Comment: Hi Thomas, thanks for your reply. Sounds like a good idea but I could not find a xdebug.trace_enable_trigger parameter in my php.ini. Which version of xdebug are you using - mine only has a xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger setting.

Comment: I'm using Xdebug 2.1.1. You could try to add this parameter if it is not already in your configuration. On some distributions, the default parameters are not listed in the configuration file

Comment: According to the [changelog](http://xdebug.org/updates.php) `xdebug.trace_enable_trigger` was added in 2.2.0